# shinydashboard column layout of box()

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard that looks like this:

[image]

```
# Packages
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
theme_set(theme_light())


header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test App",
  titleWidth = 215
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Test Tab", tabName = "test_tab",
             icon = icon("paper-plane"), startExpanded = TRUE)
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "test_tab",

            fluidRow(
              column(width = 4,
                     h2("Column X"),
                     valueBoxOutput("first_value", width = NULL),
                     box(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("second_value", width = "90%", height = "100px"),
                         title = "Second Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         collapsible = FALSE, width = NULL
                     )
              ),
              column(width = 8,
                     h2("Column Y"),

                     box(
                       title = "#3", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                       collapsible = FALSE, width = 4
                     ),
                     box(
                       title = "#4", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                       collapsible = FALSE, width = 4
                     )
              )
            ),

            fluidRow(
              h2("Row A"),

              column(width = 12,

                     box(title = "Third Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 2.4),

                     box("Fourth Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 2.4),

                     box("Fifth Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 2.4),


                     box("Sixth Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 2.4),


                     box("Seventh Value", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         width = 2.4)
              )


            )

    )
  )
)


# Put them together into a dashboardPage
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", header = header,
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = body)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$first_value <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(
      comma_format()(100000),
      subtitle = "First Value",
      icon = icon("list"), color = "purple"
    )
  })

  output$second_value = flexdashboard::renderGauge({
    flexdashboard::gauge(0.12 * 100,
                         symbol = '%',
                         min = 0, 
                         max = 100)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm trying to get the box()es below RowA to line up in a five column format, like this:

`Third Value | Fourth Value | Fifth Value | Sixth Value`

I'm not sure how I'd do that here. I've tried to put 5 boxes inside column() inside a fluidRow() which should work, but unfortunately, the boxes keep on showing up horizontally...

Is there anyway to display the boxes in column format? If not, can you guide me to other functions that resemble what I have?

Answer (score 0):

You've specified your column widths for each of these five boxes to be 2.4 (12/5 I guess).

Column widths should be whole numbers. If you substitute 2 for 2.4 it'll work fine.

Note that you will have an empty column to the right of box 5 corresponding to the 2 (12 - 2*5) positions left over.

This is based on bootstrap column layout. For more information see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) tutorial.